# QMultiMap with struct as key and struct as value, comparison operators

Tags: c++, qt, compare, operator-overloading, qmultimap

I have two structs, for example, first struct as key in `QMultiMap`:

```
struct KeyStruct
{
    int keydata1;
    int keydata2;
    int keydata3;
    bool operator < ( const KeyStruct& o ) const
    {
        return keydata1 < o.keydata1 || keydata2 < o.keydata2 || keydata3 < o.keydata3;
    }
};
```

And second struct as value:

```
struct ValueStruct
{
    int valuedata1;
    QString valuedata2;
};
```

I tried to use `QMultiMap` like this:

```
multiMap.insert( keyStruct, valueStruct ); // in a loop
foreach( keyStruct, multiMap.keys()){
    foreach( valueStruct, multiMap.values( keyStruct )){
    // it never reaches this line
    }
}
```

I'm shure in some cases I have multiple values per key, but can't even get one. I think the problem is in comparsion.
Also, I tried this:

```
bool operator == ( const KeyStruct& o ) const
{
    return keydata1 == o.keydata1 &&
           keydata2 == o.keydata2 &&
           keydata3 == o.keydata3;
}
```

But it seems `QMultiMap` just doesn't use this code in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data structure ( to my knowledge) that requires an `operator<()` to function has also the condition that:

```
A<B => ! B<A
```

This seems trivial, but in your case, it is possible that `A<B && B<A`. For instance if `A.keydata1 < B.keydata1` but `A.keydata2 > B.keydata2`.

To fix this you should write your operator something like this:

```
 bool operator < ( const KeyStruct& o ) const
{
    if(keyData1 != o.keyData1) return keyData1 < o.keyData1;
    if(keyData2 != o.keyData2) return keyData2 < o.keyData2;
    //etc
    return false; //they are equal

}
```